# Show "Share" dialog in SharePoint document library after upload

Tags: document-library, 2016

As soon as Document is uploaded in Document library the share pop should open.

Currently I am working in `SP2016`. Which provide me direct share button in document library, all I need to do is just select the document.

But what I want is as soon as any document is uploaded in document library the share PopUp should open and user don't need to search the currently uploaded one then select it and share it.

Comment: The SharePoint security model assumes that if you haven't changed the permissions inheritance between your site and document library, then the people you have placed in the default groups will already have access.  There is no need to set permissions on individual files.  This is the reason you don't get a popup asking you for permissions each time a file is uploaded.